# Hibernate Concurrent ManyToMany relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, concurrency

I am having troubles when running last test against a Kotin Spring Boot application. One critical object has a ManyToMany relationship to another one:

```
@Entity
data class Subscriber(
   
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "subscriber_message",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "message_id")],
        indexes =[
            Index(name = "idx_subscriber_message_message_id", columnList = "message_id"),
            Index(name = "idx_subscriber_message_subscriber_id", columnList = "subscriber_id")
        ]
    )
    val messages: MutableList<Message>
}


@Entity
data class Message(

  
)
```

Messages are added to a subscriber like this:

```
subscriber.messages.add(message)
save(subscriber)
```

When a new message arrives, the controller asks the repository to add the message to all existing subscribers by calling the following method:

```
@Synchronized
fun SubscriberRepository.addMessage(message: Message) {
    findAll().forEach {
            it.messages.add(message)
            save(it)
    }
}
```

We currently use MutableList for this property since we need to add new elements to the list. This type is not thread safe, so I tried the good old Java concurrent set java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet, to which Spring complained saying that this type is not supported.
Is there a better way to stay thread safe in a web application regarding such a relationship. The list of messages is consumed by a subscriber who then clears it from messages it is done with. But because of concurrency, the cleaning process doesn't work either!

Comment: Can you add the code  for `list of messages is consumed by a subscriber who then clears it from messages it is done with`?

Comment: This functionality is nested over many classes (Controller, Model...) but it ends up calling list.removeAll(confirmedMessages)

Comment: I see. When you call `list.removeAll(confirmedMessages)`, is `Subscriber` still managed by hibernate and will propagate the changes automatically to database or is it not managed by hibernate at that point?

Comment: It is all managed by Hibernate. The Subscriber list of messages is edited and then the subscriber with its list is saved by calling subscriberRepository.save(subscriber)

Comment: I don't think your `Subscriber` is managed by hibernate at the point of consuming because otherwise you don't need to call `subscriberRepository.save(subscriber)`. I would like to see service method that calls the repository to retrieve the subscriber together with any @Transactional annotations. Hibernate is not going to allow you to create concurrent collections as it has own List and Set implementations. But based on the service methods, there can be some work arounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't think JPA is going to allow it to be you to initialise it with any concurrent versions because hibernate has own implementations like `PersistentSet` etc for each collection type which it supports.
- When adding a message, you already have `synchronised`  method so that should be fine.
- Now I guess many threads trying to consume the messages from the retrieved subscriber. So why don't you do modify the subscriber like this before giving it to the threads consume it.

  - retrieve subscriber with messages
  - `subscriber.setMessages(Collections.synchronizedList(subscriber.getMessages()))` and give it to threads (I don't know what is the equivalent in kotlin)
  - So now `subscriber.messages.removeAll(confirmedMessages)` will be thread safe

Comment: But this way, I have to refill the Spring structure of messages from the concurrent copy for saving the subscriber, which brings us back to where we started!

Comment: Did you try that? I thought it shouldn't be needed as your interface is still `list` not concurrent list

Comment: Collections.synchronizedList(..) would copy the list and added messages will be only in that copy and have to be re-aded to the original spring-visible list, or am I missing something here?

Comment: No. It will not copy and it is wrapping the original collection so should work out of the box. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)